# Custom Storage Provider with asp.net core Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am working with an existing authentication API and repository that currently only exposes two methods.

```
Task<User> Login(string username, string password);

Task Logout(User user);
```

I would like to use this with asp.net core Identity.  All the application needs the ability to do is Log In, Log Out and show the current user who is logged in.

This is my current idea on how to do this.

Extend the SignInManager class as so

```
public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<User>
{
      public Override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password,
        bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
      {
               var user = await Login(userName, password);
               if (user != null)
               {
                    return SignInResult.Success;
               }
               else
               {
                    return SignInResult.Failure;
               }
      }
}
```

Then in my startup would look like this this:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

 services.AddTransient<MySignInManager>();
```

I read over this article :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers

and they suggested to implement the IUserStore and deal with the existing API from there, but after reading through the default implmentation of the SignInManager and UserManager, it seems to check the Username and password in seperate methods.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge on the subject, I am quite new to the Identity server.  Any Help would be greatly appreciated!